How Impinj speedway r420 switch the antennas
I'd like to use Impinj Speedway r420 for localization of tags with multiple antenna. To realize this, I want to know how the reader switch their antennas, such as the duration of switching, and the length of sending time and receiving time. However I couldn't find any documents about these.
Is there anyone who can tell me about these?

@jsotola I'm sorry, I explained that badly.
